# How to overwrite 'NaN' strings in a table using for-loop

Tags: string, matlab, loops, nan

I want to replace the strings 'NaN' with NaN in my table using a **loop** / or any other strategy that returns NaN, leaving all else unchanged. Here my code:

```
for k = 1:height(Z_24TimeSteps)
  if isnan(Z_24TimeSteps{k})
    Z_24TimeSteps{k} = nan;
  end
end
```

Table:
[image]

Another strategy I tried:

```
Z_24TimeSteps(cellfun(@isnan,Z_24TimeSteps))=nan;
```

How can I use this rationale for the "table" format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to use logical indexing on table columns as below.

```
Z_24TimeSteps.x1COVGY(strcmp(Z_24TimeSteps.x1COVGY,'NaN')) = {nan}
```

For multiple columns you can loop the columns as below.

```
colNames = Z_24TimeSteps.Properties.VariableNames;
for k = 1:numel(colNames)
    if iscell(Z_24TimeSteps.(colNames{k}))
        Z_24TimeSteps.(colNames{k})(strcmp(Z_24TimeSteps.(colNames{k}),'NaN')) = {nan};
    else
        Z_24TimeSteps.(colNames{k})(strcmp(Z_24TimeSteps.(colNames{k}),'NaN')) = nan;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Navan. I have tried this one but struggle doing the _loop_ over all 281 columns

Comment: I updated the answer to loop over the columns. You may need to some additional checks depending on the type of loops.